# Rails, model that has three collections of other same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections, associations, mongoid

Lets say that I got model named `Service` and `Client`. Client has `Services` that added to bookmark, `Services` that `Client` made request, `Services` that `Client` made call.

That means my `Client` has three collecitons of `Services`. Is it possible to have multiple colletions that stores same model? Will be there differences when I use SQl or MongoID?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, If I've understood your problem correctly. You have two models `Service` and `Client`. 
And the requirement `Client has Services that added to bookmark, Services that Client made request, Services that Client made call`.

Let's say I create three attributes on `Service(bookmarked, called, requested, client_id)` model to identify if service is bookmarked or called or requested and of course it'll have client id.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bookmarked_services, -> {where bookmarked: true }, :class_name => "Service"
   has_many :requested_services, -> {where requested: true }, :class_name => "Service"
   has_many :called_services, -> {where called: true }, :class_name => "Service"
end
```

I think above solution should solve your problem.

Comment: Please add code of `Service`. I want to know what it will have.

Comment: "class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
end" should be simple enough.